# facebook and twitter share count not updating on share

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

The problem is facebook and twitter count not updating on share. It is updating on Page refresh. Is this possible to display the updated count without page refresh on successful share on facebook and twitter wall.

I am using the following code

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $domainUrl;?>/en/blog-view.php?bid=<?php echo $bid;?>" data-type="button_count"></div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo $domainUrl;?>/en/blog-view.php?bid=<?php echo $blogres['blog_id'];?>">Tweet</a>
```

and i use ajax for display some more blogs

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'get_blogs.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#blogList').append(html);
                    FB.XFBML.parse();
                    twttr.widgets.load();
                    var nextPage=parseInt(LoadId)+1;
                    if(nextPage<=totalPages){
                        $("#load_more").val(nextPage); 
                    }else{
                        $("#load_more").val('0'); 
                    }
                    $("#process_page").val('0');
                }
            });
```

I use "FB.XFBML.parse();" and "twttr.widgets.load();" functions for displaying of fb and twitter counts for articles which are loaded from ajax

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can re-load both Facebook & Twitter iframes, 
`var fbIframeSource = $('iframe.fb-share').attr('src');
$('iframe.fb-share').attr('src', '').attr('src', fbIframeSource);`

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax. Ajax will refresh the particular part in a page instead of whole page.

Comment: Thank You for the replay. Can you please tell me which part of the code I will use in ajax